# Short hand notation for long chains of functional compositions

Tags: functions, notation, function-and-relation-composition, scientific-notation

I understand from an earlier Math SE query:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2719645

the following short hand notation could be used to express long chains of functional compositions (?) :

$f(x)=\bigcirc_{i=1}^n g_i$

to represent:

$f(x)= g_1 \circ \ g_2 \circ \dots \circ  g_n (x)$

I have not seen this anywhere else except the mention in Math SE. How common/known is this notation if I were to use it in my paper(s)? I don't want to mystify the reader and send them to tangential research on notation, although I could really use a short hand notation. Can anyone give me an example of a paper/publication where this is used? If this is not correct, is there an alternate short hand notation?

Comment: I am seeing it for the first time.

Comment: Here is the Math SE reference:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2719645

Comment: I am not sure that I see how your question is distinct from the linked question.  In any event, I have never seen that notation in an actual paper.  I don't see anything wrong with it---it seems like reasonable notation---but it is not (to my knowledge) terribly common.  You would almost certainly need to define it in any document in which it is used.

Comment: The distinction is that I was asking for example papers/publications where this notation has been seen.